# What is the real advantage of using React.js? Is it Virtual DOM or Unidirectional data flow? Or anything else?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

I have been using react for sometime. I would like to know what is the real advantage of react over other framework/libraries. Is it virtual dom or unidirectional data flow, or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS Development uses new technology that has not been used before in web application development. It is a perfect tool to make high-performance presentation layer for your application. And it can be even faster if you take the advantage of immutable data structures. As ReactJS features like components allow you to develop new features in React without rewriting existing code.

There are plenty of Flux implementations you can choose from, including the brand new framework Relay. The Virtual DOM feature which was not present in Angular adds an extra advantage. Having such great performing features framework like React.js is the dream of many Web Application Development Companies. So, if you are dealing with real-time data then ReactJS is the best solution.